# PHP-FPM using all the memory?

Tags: apache, php

Can the version PHP-FPM be the culprit?

I started looking at version and found that my version (5.3.24 released in 2011) and the last one 5.3.3 was the last independent version of PHP-FPM in 2012. Subsequently it was merged into the main PHP project. And  they even recommend using the new PHP version.

PHP is already on 5.6+

Could this be causing the 14gb of memory usage?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Note that since `5.3.24` there are more than 100 bug fixes and some of them are for memory leaks. Anyway upgrading to at least 5.4 is strongly recommended since the performance boost alone will be about 15%.